# Powershell sen-mailmessage script doesnt work

Tags: powershell

i'm writing a simple script to send email message via powershell
it pretty simple right now, i'll edit from - to - body - Subject etc with variables as soon it works...

this is my code

```
clear
# server smtp
$smtpserver = "smtp.xxxx.it"
# porta
$smtpport = "25"
# username completo di chiocciola
$smtpuser = "myemail@domain.it"
# password
$smtppwd = "MyPassword"
# genero la password codificata
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $smtppwd -AsPlainText -Force
# genero set credenziali da usare con la funzione
$smtpcreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($smtpuser, $secpasswd)

# funzione
Send-MailMessage -Body "test" -to myotheremail@gmail.com -from myemail@domain.it -Subject "HOPE IT WORKS NOW" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Port $smtpport -Credential $smtpcreds
```

*but i always get this error*

```
Send-MailMessage : Cassetta postale non disponibile. Risposta del server: 5.7.1 Relaying to <myotheremail@gmail.com> denied (authentication 
required)
In C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\MonitorScript\Quasi OK.ps1:16 car:1
+ Send-MailMessage -Body "test" -to myotheremail@gmail.com -from myemail@ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpFailedRecipientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you allowed to send SMTP mail this way? The most likely cause is that the SMTP server is blocking you. You may have to use SSL authentication, so you can try adding `-UseSSL` to your `Send-MailMessage` line.